# Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer to pass into sizeof()

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, language-lawyer, sizeof

In a recent post, I realised that when allocating a structure variable, passing the dereferenced pointer deemed a better practice in contrast to passing the structure type to `sizeof()`. This is basically because the former is more resilient to code changes than the latter.

Which suggests, that in the following code *method 1* is deemed a better practice than *method 2*.

```
typedef struct X_ {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
} X;

int main() {
    X* obj1 = malloc(sizeof(*obj1)); // ----> method 1
    X* obj2 = malloc(sizeof(X));     // ----> method 2
    return 0;
}
```

The question is, how valid is it to dereference `obj1` in *method 1* ? Inside `malloc`, `obj1` is still unconstructed/uninitialized memory which suggests that dereferencing of `obj1` happening inside `sizeof()` shouldn't be valid.

Let me make a guess what makes *method 1* valid. Is this because since `sizeof()` is a compile time operation dereferencing `obj1` gets translated into *method 2* by the compiler?

Could someone please elaborate the technical validity of this by referring to the relevant C standards?

Comment: You are not dereferencing anything ... `sizeof` does not evaluate its operand (except for VLAs), ie `sizeof (42/0)` does not attempt to divide by zero :)

Comment: @pmg I'm a bit confused by "you are not dereferencing anything"...I understand `sizeof` does not evaluate its operand except in the case of VLAs...but still, if `sizeof(*obj1)` is not dereferencing `obj1` (which is a pointer to `X`) to get `X`, then what do we call this? Is it because this is a compile-time operation that it isn't considered "dereferencing"?

Comment: @dwillis77: `sizeof` only cares about the **type**. The **type** of `*obj` is the same whatever the value of `obj` is (even if `obj` has an invalid/indeterminate/trap value). The type of `int/int` (`42/0`) is `int` even if the value has no meaning :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sizeof expression where the operand is not a variable length array is a non evaluated expression. So this expression

```
sizeof(*obj1)
```

is well-formed.

From the C Standard (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 2 The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which
> may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is
> determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer.
> **If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the
> result is an integer constant**

As for your question relative to the best method of specifying an argument of malloc

```
X* obj1 = malloc(sizeof(*obj1)); // ----> method 1
X* obj2 = malloc(sizeof(X));     // ----> method 2
```

then if the type `X` is visible in the point of using malloc like in this case

```
X* obj1 = malloc(sizeof(*obj1)); // ----> method 1
```

then this approach is preferable.

However if the type is not visible like for example

```
obj1 = malloc(sizeof(*obj1)); // ----> method 1
```

then I prefer explicitly to specify the type like

```
obj1 = malloc(sizeof( X ));
```

Otherwise for example this code snippet

```
p = malloc( *p );
q = malloc( *q );
```

does not give enough information for the reader of the code. And the reader will need to scroll the source code forward and backward to find the declarations of `p` and `q` to determine their types.

Comment: It is arguable that the same benefits obtained with `obj1 = malloc(sizeof(*obj1))` can be had with `obj1 = (X*)malloc(sizeof( X ));`

Comment: @chqrlie only the first version is invariant to changes of obj1's type. If you change the type, then `(type)malloc(sizeof type)` requires editing 2 additional places in the code, whereas `malloc(sizeof *object)` does not (and will always be correct). You gain absolutely nothing by casting the result of malloc.

Comment: @FelixG: if you have decent warnings enabled (`-Wall -Werror`), you get a type mismatch. The cast could come from a macro: `#define new_object(type)  ((type *)malloc(sizeof(type)))`. Local coding conventions could include something like this and the alternative `obj1 = malloc(sizeof(*obj1))` is not available if you pass the object directly as a function argument: `append_node(new_object(Node))`

Answer (score 2):

> *The question is, how valid is it to dereference `obj1` in method 1?*

It's 100% valid. You could use it without parenthesis though, `sizeof *obj1`.

From [N1570 ISO/IEC 9899:201x §6.5.3.4 The sizeof and _Alignof operators](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4)

> 2 -
> *The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. **The size is determined from the type of the operand**. The result is an integer. <s>If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated;</s> **otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant.***

In fact one can say it's a preferable method, the reason being that if you change, for some reason, the type of the object it's easy to forget to also change the `sizeof` argument, using the derefenced pointer will avoid this potencial silent error.